# Comparação de datas

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony-2

Eu pretendo que apareça a mensagem de quando o utilizador não insira data nenhuma ou que a data inicial seja maior que a data final.
O código que eu fiz foi este:

```
/**
 * @Assert\True(message = "Erro! Verifique as horas. Data inical não pode ser maior que a data final.")
 */
public function isHoraFim() 
{
    if ($this->horainicial > $this->horafim) 
    {
        return false;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }

    if ($this->horainicial || $this->horafim) 
    {
        return false;
    }    

    return $this->horainicio < $this->horafim;
}
```

Mas a mensagem de erro aparece sempre, menos quando o utilizador não insere data nenhuma.

Comment: `$this->horafim` seria `$this->horafinal`?

Comment: devia ser fim eu já alterei, mas mesmo assim não está a funcionar bem

Comment: Qual o tipo das propriedades(variáveis)? Tem como mostrar a definição delas, como você esta tratando os dados após o usuário inserir os horas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deixo aqui a resolução há minha pergunta para quem tiver a mesma dúvida do que eu.
O que se passou comigo foi de ter chama o mesmo nome do que a minha variável o programa estava a considerar aquilo como variável então estava se a confundir.

```
 /**
 * @Assert\True(message = "Erro! Verifique as horas. Data inical não pode ser maior que a data final.")
 */
public function isHorasCheck() {
        return ($this->horainicio < $this->horafim);
}
```

O que eu acrescentei, mas que não estava na pergunta, achei que ficaria melhor assim.

```
 /**
 * @Assert\True(message = "Erro! Verifique as horas. Data inical não pode ser maior que a data final.")
 */
public function isHorasCheck() {

    if ($this->horafim === null){
        return true;
    }
    if ($this->horainicio === null){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return ($this->horainicio < $this->horafim);
    }

}
```

Tanto uma maneira como outra funcionam agora é só verem o que é melhor para vocês.

Comment: Se sua solução serviu, não se esqueça de validar sua própria resposta :)

Comment: eu sei mas só aqui a dois dias é que o programa me deixa validar.

Answer (score 0):

Se você precisa retornar true ou false, uma simples linha resolve:

```
/**
 * @Assert\False(message = "Erro! Verifique as horas. Data inicial não pode ser maior que a data final.")
 */
public function isHoraFim() 
{
    return (!$this->horainicial || !$this->horafim || $this->horainicial > $this->horafim);
}
```

Ou:

```
/**
 * @Assert\True(message = "Erro! Verifique as horas. Data inicial não pode ser maior que a data final.")
 */
public function isHoraFim() 
{
    return ($this->horainicial && $this->horafim && $this->horainicial < $this->horafim);
}
```

Comment: não está a fazer a mesma coisa do que o meu.

Comment: Inverti os asserts. Na verdade a mensagem será emitida se o método retornar `false` no `Assert\True`, ou vice-versa.

Comment: Mesmo assim nada, o que eu pretendia era que quando o utilizador carrega-se num botão de guardar e sem ter preenchido os dados das horas que apareça a mensagem de erro ou hora inicial ser maior que a hora final e que não aparece-se mensagem nenhuma quando está certo.

Comment: As outras mensagens de erro que você define com `Assert` aparecem normalmente nas validações de formulários?

Comment: Creio que não..

Comment: As asserções definem condições que devem ser satisfeitas quando o usuário posta um formulário e você valida com `$form->isValid()`. Se o formulário for inválido você exibe os erros gerados para o usuário.

Comment: Mas tenho de fazer isso aqui na entity Intervencao.php ou na IntervecaoController ou na Intervencao.new?

Comment: Na `IntervencaoController`. Geralmente é no controlador onde reside toda a parte de interação com usuário – como entrada de dados, validação, resposta com mensagens de erro ou sucesso.

Comment: Mas a function isHoraFim tenho de declarar na Intervenção.Php só o resto é que tenho de fazer na INtervencaoController?

Comment: Isso mesmo! As validações ficam nas models.

Comment: E no meu método só tenho de colocar $form->isValid();??

Comment: Mas não é $form->isValid(); não é $form->isHoraFim(); Eu fiz assim $form= $this->isHoraFim();.

Comment: Vamos continuar a discussão em http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21040/discussion-between-catarina-silvestre-and-rodrigo-rigotti